# Dell XPS 9560 Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after login without AC only in Intel mode

Tags: 18.04, dell, intel-graphics, freeze, login-screen

I am having trouble with my new 18.04 installation while logging in **Intel mode without AC only**, when power cable is plugged in everything boots fine in any mode.
I installed drivers (nvidia 390) and configured:

```
GRUB2 "quiet splash intel_pstate=enable acpi_rev_override=1 nouveau.modeset=0"
```

Everything works fine, but I need good up-time from my battery, and with working Nvidia adapter this unreal (almost 30 watt in idle power consumption). So I disabled it with `nvidia-prime` and after reboot got freeze right after I input my password on login screen and hit enter, I see a blank color page and a frozen cursor. Tried dozens time.

P.S. Wayland doesn't help.

What shall I do, please advise!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same configuration as you, same nvidia driver. Though I do get more freezes with switching nvidia-prime than it was on an older device, it does not freeze as badly as in your case after reboot. I am able to use the intel mode.

I noticed my **/etc/default/grub** looks different from yours (if that is what you meant). Try putting:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.runpm=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```